# How to style tables on successive pages of a paged media output?

Tags: css, pagination, paging, css-paged-media

I have an html table like this:

```
<div class="report">
    <table>
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tfoot>...</tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row-to-style">...</tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Note that all tbody's above are identically structured. I want to style the very first  tr.row-to-style row differently from the others.  Each tbody will have a tr.row-to-style but I want to only affect the first such row on a page. The output is paged media, specifically PrinceXML produced pdf files from xhtml source files. This means we can use advanced css selectors, cross-browser compatibility is not required, and javascript cannot be used.

It's easy enough to style the target row on the first page of output. I can use:

```
table tfoot + tbody tr.row-to-style {...}
```

Also, if I know how many tbody's will fit on a page, I can do something like:

```
table tbody:nth-of-type(4n+1) tr.row-to-style {...}
```

But if I don't know the number of tbody's that will fit on a page, how can I target the first one?

On output, in effect, the thead and tfoot sections are repeated for each page. The tables were designed this way specifically to take advantage of this. We allow for page breaks after a tbody. The output may contain several pages.

Thus, the output has sort of a pseudo-thead and pseudo-tfoot on each page. But I see no way of using such to mark the first tbody on a page. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: What you mean by "page" seems very confused from sentence to sentence - HTML page in a browser? A ranged set of of data within a larger set?

Comment: Also: what's wrong with ":first-child" or ".first"?

Comment: It's paged media. Paged media doesn't occur when you are viewing web pages normally, it's just one big page that scrolls. Paged media occurs when you're printing an html page, or, as I'm doing here, creating a pdf from xhtml source using PrinceXML.

The key thing here is that when outputting to paged media, the thead and tfoot sections repeat themselves automagically on each page. Thus, the xhtml source has one thead, one tfoot, and then a varying number of tbody's. These tbody's will be divided among the pages, and each will have a thead and tfoot.

Comment: tbody:first-child doesn't actually work in this case. I'm not sure why. Perhaps it has something to do with thead, tfoot, tbody all being table-row-groups. Neither does tbody:nth-child(1) with various numbers for 1. tbody:nth-of-type(1) works, and is equivalent to tfoot + tbody. But this works on the first page only - not subsequent pages.

Answer (score 0):

There just doesn't seem to be any documentation that talks about the possibility of targeting css based off the "page box" that the `@page` creates. Everything talks about how the `@page` creates a "page box" but nothing about how to access or point to that page box for styling of child elements on a page. These are all shots in the dark, untested, and likely not valid, but maybe...

```
@page tbody:first-child tr.row-to-style { styles go here }
```

Or perhaps some use of named pages? Like:

```
@page nameOfPage {}
tbody:first-child tr.row-to-style {page: nameOfPage; other styles go here}
```

Or something like `@media` defining:

```
@page {
    tbody:first-child tr.row-to-style { styles go here}
}
```

Or maybe (since I assume the content is generated on each page for `thead` and `tfoot`, which should theoretically place `thead` before the first `tbody` of each page):

```
thead + tbody tr.row-to-style { styles go here }
```

Honestly, I don't expect any of these to work, but you can give them a try. The problem seems to be that the real `tfoot` is only defined once at the top of the *source* and therefore the css selectors do not recognize the page generated one's as existing for styling purposes.

Comment: I think your last statement seems quite correct, though I need to wade through the alistapart article on 'Printing a Book with CSS', the mentioned book (by authors associated with both the invention of CSS and PrinceXML) and the W3C page media standards to be really sure. btw the thead + tbody doesn't seem to work, tfoot follows thead in the html, so only tfoot + tbody works (but only for the first page). I'll check out @page more closely.